# HTTP 404 vs 400 for invalid query parameters

Tags: http-status-code-404, query-string, http-status-code-400, http-status

Here is my request URL:

http://server.com/app/user/getuser/?userId=9999

Note that `userId` is query parameter. Not embedded path parameter.

I understand that if the request URL is: http://server.com/app/user/getuser/9999 and the ID 9999 does not exist in database, The code 404 should be used.

**BUT what HTTP status should be used for the case `userId` is query parameter**? Right now I am returning 400 instead of 404.

Answer (score 21):

I would use **404 Not Found**.

### Why?

The [**RFC 7231**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) defines a **400 Bad Request** response like this:

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

...since your request is valid and you are just trying to access a resource that does not exist, I think a **404 Not Found** status is more suitable. [**RFC 7231**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) defines its meaning like this:

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: Great that helped me the other way around!

Comment: But the server has received the request, processed it and returned the valid response, which may or may not be an empty list

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if the "user" is the resource, a better way to expose that resource is to use a URL like this: http://server.com/app/user/9999

Query parameters are best for searching a dataset, where an empty answer is still valid (200).

But, if you can't change the URL, 404 in this case is a valid option.